# Firefox not passing values from an input text field to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, input

I have a problem with firefox passing information into a javascript function.  The following code works ok on Chrome, Safari and Opera.  It has some issues in IE9 but overall does what it is supposed to.

Firefox however simply ignores the onchange and onclick with the console reporting "query is not defined".  If there is a way around this or a different approach I'd love to know.

```
<div class="viewstory_controls_content">
                Search
                <input type="text" id="query" onchange="javascript:submitForm('../scripts/php/search.php', 'search_results',query,'main')" name="query"></input>
                <button class="viewstory_search" onclick="javascript:submitForm('../scripts/php/search.php', 'search_results', query, 'main')">
                    <div class="viewstory_search_content">
                        Search
                    </div>
                </button>
            </div>
```

submit query:

```
function submitForm(url, target, term, type) {
    // native XMLHttpRequest object
    term = term.value;
    url = url + "?term=" + term + "&type=" + type;
    alert("url:" + url + "\ntarget:" + target + "\nterm:" + term);
    document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = 'sending...';
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            jahDone(target);
        };
        req.open("GET", url, true);
        req.send(null);
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        if (req) {
            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                submitFormDone(target);
            };
            req.open("GET", url, true);
            req.send();
        }
    }
}​
```

Comment: and this submitForm() function looks like....?

Comment: If your error is 'query is not defined' and you're not showing us where you initialise 'query', we can't really help much

Comment: Sorry should have see the need of that...

Comment: query is the id of the input text field

Comment: You can not just submit the id of your element and think javascript will know what you mean. If you want to submit the whole element then you should use findelementbyid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because the browsers said to support your script actually look for a field whose `name` attribute is equal to `query` (please note I'm not 100% sure on this). As far as I know, this never worked in Firefox.
Simply replace `query` in the event handlers with `document.getElementById('query')`. In the `onchange` handler of the `input`, you can use `this` instead of `query` as well.
Also, don't use `javascript:` in inline event handlers. It's obsolete.

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to accept the answers that helped you by clicking the accept button.

Answer (score 0):

term is the third parameter , you are passing query there in function call like a variable. It is not defined anywhere . Pass the value of the field query